# Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `error` of type `string` expected `boolean`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a material-ui Textfield component in my ReactJS project.

When I run my code, the warning I got in the console is:

```
index.js:1 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `error` of type `string` supplied to `ForwardRef(TextField)`, expected `boolean`.
```

My component code is below.

```
 <TextField
   required
   error={errorMessages.myErrorMessage}
   helperText={errorMessages.myErrorMessage}
   value={myTextField}
  />
```

This code works totally fine but the problem is that it gives a warning message in the console.

I want an error message to be shown only if "errorMessages.myErrorMessage" value is not an empty string.

Is there any ES6 or any other solution to this?

Comment: Try this (errorMessages.myErrorMessage == 'true')

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `error` property of `TextField` expects an boolean, but you are passing it a string.

If you want to display an error if `errorMessages.myErrorMessage` is not an empty string you can check the length of the string, e.g.:

```
<TextField
   required
   error={errorMessages.myErrorMessage.length > 0}
   helperText={errorMessages.myErrorMessage}
   value={myTextField}
/>
```

Alternatively you can also use `!!errorMessages.myErrorMessage` instead of `errorMessages.myErrorMessage.length > 0`.
This uses of the fact that an empty string is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Glossary/Falsy) and all other strings are [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Glossary/Truthy)

Comment: wow! how couldn't I think of this. Thanks!!. Both works so I choose short one which is "!!" notation. Is there any performance difference between both ways?

Comment: @BahadırKorumaz performance should be pretty much the same between the two

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to do this

```
 <TextField
   required
   error={!!errorMessages.myErrorMessage}
   helperText={errorMessages.myErrorMessage}
   value={myTextField}
  />
```

By this way you are passing false if errorMessages.myErrorMessage is empty string. And the react component expects error to be type boolean, either true or false.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use with optional chaining along with this fix

```
{!!errorMessages?.myErrorMessage}
```

Answer (score 0):

actually your error={!!errorMessages.myErrorMessage} executing everytime doesnt matter there is error or not so please use if condition like "errorMessages ? errorMessages.myErrorMessage : void 0 " and also avoid to pass boolean value like true or false ...... Happy coding

Comment: this way we still pass string because our errorMessages.myErrorMessage is still a string. Isn't it?

Comment: I dont think this string . Otherwise you can check either its string or boolean just write typeof myerrormessages

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is you should convert the error props value to **Boolean** by making use of **!!** like below.

```
  <TextField
     required
     error={!!errorMessages.myErrorMessage}
     helperText={errorMessages.myErrorMessage}
     value={myTextField}
   />
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I got this issue `InputLabelProps={{ shrink: field.value }}` for TextField using material ui so I go this issue:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `shrink` of type `string` supplied to `ForwardRef(InputLabel)`, expected `boolean`.
```

So I fixed the issue by simply getting a boolean value of `field.value`

```js
InputLabelProps={{ shrink: Boolean(field.value) }}
```

Here is the complete code:

```js
<Box mt={2}>
  <Controller
    name="password"
    control={control}
    render={({ field }) => (
      <TextField
        type={showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
        ...
        {...register('password', {
          required: 'Veuillez insirer votre mot de passe',
          validate: {
            password: (value) => mustBePassword(value),
          },
        })}
        fullWidth
        name="password"
        label="Mot de passe"
        id="password"
        InputLabelProps={{ shrink: Boolean(field.value) }}
        helperText={errors.password?.message}
        error={!!errors.password}
      />
    )}
  />
</Box>
```